# Look up information in onetable to populate values in a form bounded to another table

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

I have an excel sheet with information about each employee. I keep getting new updated spreadsheet every month. I have to create a database managing cases related to the employees. I have a database and the bounded form already created for the cases which also contain emp info fields. What I am trying to do is to only type in the emp id in the form and want the form to look up in the spreadsheet(which can be a table in the cases db) and populate other fields in the form and that information can go into the cases db. Can this be done?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you have an Access database with tables that are linked to Excel files? You are using an Access form and you want it to  display information from one of the linked tables when selecting an emp id?

Comment: No. I do not have the database connected to excel files. I want the form to populate the information from the excel(with emp info) when one field(emp id) is entered in the form and that information needs to be stored into the cases db(I was assuming that I would do this by bounding the form and the cases db)

Comment: You mention cases db as though it is a separate database to the one you are currently in; is this the case? And is there a reason why you are not using linked (Excel) tables?

Comment: No!Cases is the only db that I have that is linked to the form. To avoid human error, I don't want users to put in comples info in the fields in the form. Instead, the user can just enter emp id in the form and the form will populate the other fields, like "name", "salary", etc.(from the spreadsheet) in the form and this info will eventually go into the cases DB

Comment: @AndrewGibson tagging you for comments

Comment: I do not know from the details supplied why you are not using linked Excel files or, alternatively, using an importing process to copy the Excel data in Access tables. Without taking one of these approaches, then you will IMO require a lot of code to get data from Excel (probably using an ADO connection), and to store it *somewhere*, and keep it in-sync with the Access database. Sorry I cannot help you further.

Comment: I am not against getting the excel sheet into an Access table. I said that in my first question. I just wanted you to know that that is how I am getting my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Employee information is available within the current database, perhaps in a linked (Excel), table there are a number of ways to approach this, one of which is:

- Create a form based on the Employees table, showing the fields that you are interested in auto-populating
- Delete the `RecordSource` of the form
- Delete the `ControlSource` for each of the controls on the form. You need to do this otherwise they will all initially display with the error #Name?
- Set the `Locked` or `Enabled` property of these controls to Yes or No respectively, so that the information they will display will not be editable
- Add a, for example, `Combo Box` to the form; you can accept the third option in the Controls Wizard to help you populate this. You need the EmployeedID as the first column, but can add additional columns
- Delete the `Embedded Macro` that Access creates (or Macro for Access 2003 or earlier) for the `AfterUpdate` event
- Click the build button for this event (...) and create some code.

Here is some code I used with my sample Staff Database:

```
Private Sub cboStaff_AfterUpdate()
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT StaffID, Title, FirstName, Surname FROM " _
        & "tblStaff WHERE StaffID = " & Me.cboStaff
    With Me
        .txtStaffID.ControlSource = "StaffID"
        .txtTitle.ControlSource = "Title"
        .txtFirstName.ControlSource = "FirstName"
        .txtSurname.ControlSource = "Surname"
    End With
End Sub
```

Whenever the user selects a staff (or employee) member from the combobox this will retrieve the data from the table and populate the various controls on the form. These controls will not be editable as they will be locked or not-enabled. (You can also set the Allow Additions and Allow Deletions properties of the form to No, but Allow Edits needs to remain as Yes, otherwise the combobox won't work.)

This code can be improved. In particular, to only set the `RecordSource` and `ControlSource` s once.

Obviously I am not aware of the specifics of your database, and there are other ways to approach this.

**Added** If, however, the `RecordSource` for the form is some other table that you are hoping to populate with some details from the Employees table then, instead of changing the RecordSource and ControlSource as indicated, you could use ADO (in the AfterUpdate event of the combobox) to create a `RecordSet` containing a single row (the chosen employee's details) and set the values (the `Text`) of controls on the form to the values from this recordset. As I say, there are a number of ways to approach this.

**Added** In response to:

> "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because
>   they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key or
>   relationship...."

I don't know your precise set-up but I can tell you why this is happening. The default behaviour in Access is that, for a bound form, if a change is made to any one of the bound fields, then an attempt to navigate away from the record will cause Access to save the record.

Is the form bound when it doesn't need to be? Or have you set the `ControlSource` of a control to a field when it doesn't need to be? If this is not the case then:

In the `BeforeUpdate` event of the form you can set the `Cancel` argument to True to prevent the update (or insert). However, this will prevent ANY new record from being inserted. You can either have a Button that the user needs to click to explicitly save the record, or, in the `BeforeUpdate` event, test some condition with `If` to decide whether you will allow the insert (or update) or to stop the record from being saved (by setting `Cancel = True`).

Comment: Can I have a form which will populate the values based on the table and if the record is not in the table, it'll let me enter the values manually through the form?

Comment: Well, yes, you can :) is the simple answer. A simpler approach is to have a button on the form that opens another form with its `Data Entry` property set to Yes (only to be used to create new records). On closing this second form it requeries the combobox (or whatever control(s) you are using) on the first form, so that it includes the new record you have added.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I did exactly what you told me and it worked beautifully. Only problem is, When I populate the values with one ID then I change the ID on the form again to populate another records, it gives me an error which says "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key or relationship....". I am not even clicking the submit button I created which will actually insert the values in the table. I just updated the text field that contains ID. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: tagging you for notification

Comment: I've added to my answer as the text was too long to be a comment.

Comment: I did try that. It doesn't work. I DO want a button on the insert form which will get the data into the table that is bounded to the other navigation form. My insertion form is not bounded to any table. If only I can get this fixed, I'll be done with this project!

Comment: In the code you provided, I changed the 1st line. This is how I have it in my code: Me.RecordSource = "SELECT EID, Ename, phone, email FROM Emp where EID = [Forms]![Emp]![EID]"

Comment: Again, it is difficult for me to tell exactly. However, your sql statements suggests that you are using the same control (a textbox?) as both a *lookup* feature and a bound control. This is a bad idea. My sample was using an (unbound) combobox which is used to populate other controls on the form.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! I removed the part where I set the ID on the form(I don't know why I was doing that) and it worked! Thanks mate!